# Chatbot not showing weather using python_weather module

Tags: python, chatbot

I am creating a basic chatbot that can currently tell you the current weather conditions and temperature. However, when I ask it to tell me the temperature or weather conditions, it doesn't givea any output at all, not even an exception.
Here is my code:

```
#This is the main.py

import numpy as np
import getweather as gw
from getweather import get_weather_forecast, get_current_temp
import tracemalloc
import asyncio

weather_cmds = np.array(["What is the weather like?", "What is the current weather?", "What is the weather right now?"])
temp_qs = np.array(["What is the temperature today?", "Is it hot or cold right now?", "What is the temperature like?", "What is the temperature right now?"])
greetings = np.array(["Hello.", "Hi!", "Hey!", "Hey there!"])
questions = np.array(["How can I help?", "What can I do for you?", "What do you need help with?"])
Hellos = np.concatenate((greetings, questions))

greeting = np.random.choice(greetings)
question = np.random.choice(questions)

task = input(f"{greeting} {question}\n>> ")

if task in weather_cmds:
    location = input("Enter country: ")
    tracemalloc.start()
    print(asyncio.run(get_weather_forecast(location)))
    tracemalloc.stop()

elif task in temp_qs:
    if task in temp_qs[0] or task in temp_qs[3]:
        location = input("Enter country: ")
        tracemalloc.start()
        print(asyncio.run(get_current_temp(location)))
        tracemalloc.stop()
```

```
#this is the getweather module
import python_weather
import tracemalloc
import random

async def get_weather_forecast(location):
    async with python_weather.Client() as client:
        try:
            weather = await client.get(location)
            weather_descrip = weather.current.description.lower()
            return f"In {location}, it is {weather.current.temperature}°C and {weather_descrip}."
        except python_weather.exceptions.BadApiKeyError:
            return "API key is invalid."
        except python_weather.exceptions.NotFoundError:
            return f"Could not find weather information for {location}."
async def get_current_temp(location):
    async with python_weather.Client() as client:
        weather = await client.get(location)
        return f"The temperature is {weather.current.temperature}°C in {location}."
```

I have checked through all of my print statements, they seem fine, and I have reinstalled python_weather expecting the issue to be solved but nothing worked and there wasn't any output whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way, after lots of debugging and modification...

So I started by debugging and I found that the connection was successful, but it wasn't running any return or print() lines of code.

As It turns out, there was a new update to `python_weather` which no longer supports the units argument, so I removed it and it works now!

This is the correct code:

```
import python_weather
import random
import asyncio

async def get_weather_forecast(location):
    async with python_weather.Client() as client:
        try:
            weather = await client.get(location)
            weather_descrip=weather.current.description.lower()
            return f"In {location}, it is {weather.current.temperature}°C and {weather_descrip}."
        except python_weather.exceptions.BadApiKeyError:
            return "API key is invalid"
        except python_weather.exceptions.NotFoundError:
            return f"Could not find weather information for {location}."

async def get_current_temp(location):
    async with python_weather.Client() as client:
        weather=await client.get(location)
        responses = [
            f"In {location}, it is {weather.current.temperature}°C",
            f"The current temperature in {location} is {weather.current.temperature}°C",
            f"{weather.current.temperature}°C is the current temperature in {location}"
        ]
        return random.choice(responses)
```